# a linear algebra problem in part of problem in modular form

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-forms

I am trying to solve a problem in modular form, I want to show that 
$\Gamma_1(N)
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & p
\end{array} \right)
\Gamma_1(N)  $
$= \{ \gamma \in M_2(Z) \mid det \gamma$ $=p , \gamma\equiv
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & * \\
0 & p
\end{array} \right)(modN)  $}

One part of it is clear , I can show every element im left side is in the form right hand side. but I could not show the other part.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why is this a linear algebra problem...because of the matrices?

Comment: Yes, maybe I am not right.